Money filter rendering raw codes
I encountered as issue where when changing the sizes the price not only gets reset to the default format but the <span> tag that controls the snippet becomes visible like this:
<span class="money">Rs 4,000.00</span>

The code snippet that handles this is:
<div class="product__price fs-body-base">
  <span data-price>{{ current_variant.price | money }}</span>
  <span class="visually-hidden" data-compare-text>{{ 'productproducregular_price' | t }}</span>
  <s data-compare-price>
    {% if current_variant.compare_at_price > current_variant.price %}
      {{ current_variant.compare_at_price | money }}
    {% endif %}
  </s>
  {% render 'unit-price' item: current_variant %}
</div
{% render 'product-form' with
  product: product,
  current_variant: current_variant,
  show_quantity: section.settings.show_quantity_input,
  show_dynamic_checkout: section.settings.enable_payment_button,
  show_swatches: section.settings.show_swatches,
%}
</div>

I tried using the filter money_without_currency but that didn't work.
Then I tried removing the logic that handles money variants for each size but that didn't work either.
